# Error when trying to access Lambda logs on CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I created some Lambda-Edge functions but I'm unable to set up the logs for it. When trying to access them I am seeing the error message:

> There was an error loading Log Streams. Please try again by refreshing
>   this page.

I have gone to everything I could find on google, but as far as I can see my permissions are set up fine. I've created a custom role for them **like this**.

[image]

**The role contains the following permissions:**

[image]

I can't really figure out, what else could cause this error. It has been around 2h since setting up the functions and permissions.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing the same problem. There is a weird quirk to LambdaEdge.

**The logs will be stored in the AWS location closest to the user that executes it.**

Even if you've deployed your functions in us-east-1, switch location to the destination that is closest to you.